# Preview form data from a modal in another modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a form preview from `form1` into another modal via jquery. I built the form in `modal1` and trying to pass its data into `modal2`. But it's not working in the next modal.

- Cannot pass the data from `modal1` - formData is not defined
- I need the `modal2` to get data from submitted

**HTML**

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="xModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="xModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="submit" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="xModalLabel"><em class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></em> form1</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="form1">

          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" value="hello" />
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" value="kitty" />
          <button type="submit" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#prvwModal" data-toggle="modal">
            preview
          </button>
        </form>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- preview Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="prvwModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="prvwModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="prvwModalLabel"><em class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></em>prvw loading...</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"></div>
      <div class="modal-footer"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#xModal').modal('show');

$('#xModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#form1').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('xModal sumitted');
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    $('#prvwModal').find('.modal-body').text(formData);
    $('#prvwModal').find('.modal-title').text('#form1 Preview');
  });
  console.log('xModal loaded');
});

$('#prvwModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  console.log('prvwModal loaded'+formData);
})
```

Jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/yfpruygs/7/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your inputs need a name field in order to get form data:

```
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" value="hello" />
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname" value="kitty" />
```

You will also need to change the button type to "button" if you don't plan for the preview button to actually submit the form.

```
<button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#prvwModal" data-toggle="modal">
```

Then you can use a click event...

```
  $('#form1').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log('xModal sumitted');
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    $('#prvwModal').find('.modal-body').text(formData);
    $('#prvwModal').find('.modal-title').text('#form1 Preview');
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yfpruygs/9/

Comment: That's working! Can i have one more question (please don't push me to create a new topic because it consequence). How can I extract an array - only `fname`, for example?

Comment: You could use `$(this).serializeArray()` to get an array that is JSON ready!

Comment: It's working this time so I access the array with `obj[0]['value']`